# Changing Section Title from H2 to H1 from WordPress Theme

Tags: wordpress, page-title

As the title states, I am having trouble locating where to change the section titles that are currently h2 to be h1.

Site in reference: http://veloxity.us

Any insight or advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: You need to make the changes in the theme file(s).

Comment: @user3869776, is there a reason you unaccepted the answer?

Answer (score 0):

In the "sections.php" page in the "functions/templates" folder on line ~112 and ~219 there is:

```
<?php echo ($section_post->post_title) ? '<h2>' . apply_filters('the_title', $section_post->post_title) . '</h2><div class="clear"></div>' : ''; ?>
```

and

```
<?php echo ($section_post->post_title) ? '<h2>' . apply_filters('the_title', $section_post->post_title) . '</h2><div class="clear"></div>' : ''; ?>
```

Changing the `<h2>` to `<h1>` should achieve what you are wanting.